# In Wordpress how to remove title of post in new Yoast plugin breadcrumbs setup?

Tags: wordpress, plugin, yoast

I have a Wordpress 5.4x website. I have installed Yoast 13.x SEO plugin into it and it's configured OK.

I also have breadcrumbs on my site using this Yoast plugin. To hide the title of the post in the breadcrumb's row, I have the following hack in WP's functions.php:

```
function remove_breadcrumb_title( $link_output) {
if(strpos( $link_output, 'breadcrumb_last' ) !== false ) {
    $link_output = '';
}
return $link_output;
}
add_filter('wpseo_breadcrumb_single_link', 'remove_breadcrumb_title' );
```

So the hack above works. I now am considering updating Yoast SEO plugin to latest 14.x. Does anyone have a new update to the code above to work with Yoast 14.x in case I install it later?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you don't need to change the code for it to work in new upgrades of Yoast SEO. But, there may be a change of code in other major future upgrades of the plugin.

In that case, you need to check the official Yoast website for updates or if your problem isn't listed there, you would need to contact them directly either through the WordPress forum or in their official website.

Comment: here is the official website https://yoast.com/help/implement-wordpress-seo-breadcrumbs/ and here a few examples https://gist.github.com/amboutwe/4b7a2f01366399281a53c355c5b78801/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you instead hide it using CSS?

```
 #BreadcrumbsDivName{
   visibility:none;
 }
```